# WCF - do not serialize (emit) empty collections

Tags: c#, wcf, serialization, collections

We are implementing an Client / Server application. Data are sent throughout the LAN. Where LAN means company network with several sites / locations.

We are using WCF and NetTcpBinding (**EDIT**: VS2010 .net 4.0).

I know that `[DataMember(EmitDefaultValue = false)]` is not recommended by Microsoft. But as mentionend above, data might be sent from one site to another. Therefore: **size really matters!**

Not sending the default value works most of the time fine. I have just an issue with collections of any kind. I do not want to transfer empty collections!

So I usually end up with to members of the same type (one for work, one work network) and I need to implement the methods OnSerializing and OnDeserialized.

```
[DataMember(EmitDefaultValue = false)]
private List<someType> data = new List<someType>();

[NonSerialized]
private List<someType> network = new List<someType>();

[OnDeserialized]
private void OnDeserialized(StreamingContext c)
{
    if (network == null)
        data = new List<someType>();
    else
        data = network;
}

[OnSerializing]
private void OnSerializing(StreamingContext c)
{
    if (data.Count > 0)
        network = data;
    else
        network = null;
}
```

Is there any elegant way to do that?

Or maybe even a completely different approach?

Remark: for simplicity I did not care about possible multi-threading issues.

Comment: With WCF i noticed Collection tend to be seen as standard array so `new List<someType>();` on the client is seen as `new someType[]` Also do you have to use net TCP abesolutely ? because that a bit sad to use all the bells and whistle of recent WCF technology with old binding methods

Comment: @Frank yes transport is done as Array. But the De-Serializer generates then a List. Nevertheless an empty array is sent.

Comment: Did you actually estimate how much bandwidth/time you could spare with this?

Comment: @fejesjoco I have many "optional" properties. By setting the Name parameter and not sending the default value, the size was reduced by 30-50%

Answer (score 1):

> But as mentionend above, data might be sent from one site to another.
>   Therfore: size really matters!

Do you really think that a few Bytes will make a big difference using NetTcpBinding in a LAN ? Did you made a load test to show that.

> I know that [DataMember(EmitDefaultValue = false)] is not recommended
>   by Microsoft

It's not recommanded because it's not interoperable. This recomandation does not apply to your case as you have only WCF Clients/Server on a NetTcpBinding. The config already does not support interop (through java or php).

The WCF binary encoder (uned in NetTcpBinding) supports Gzip/Deflate compression since .net 4.5. You will gain more Bytes with this feature than removing empty collections.
Read more [here](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/aa751889%28v=vs.110%29.aspx).

Comment: +1 for telling me that the recommendation does not apply to my case - didn't read MSDN thoroughly enough

Comment: "a few Bytes will make a big difference" - that totally depends. Even the binary serialization will generate an XML first and the encode this message as binary. In my case that empty Array might sum up to 3-5% on a dataobject (in XML representation)

Comment: _We should forget about small efficiencies, say about 97% of the time: premature optimization is the root of all evil. Yet we should not pass up our opportunities in that critical 3%. A good programmer will not be lulled into complacency by such reasoning, he will be wise to look carefully at the critical code; but only after that code has been identified"_ — Donald Knuth. I understand you intention to be efficient, but you may have better things to do now than optimizing bandwdth usage.